# Laravel - Wasabi Storage + Bunny CDN - Problem with url

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, cdn, wasabi, bunnycdn

I have a script running on Laravel framework. I use Wasabi S3 + Bunny CDN for file storage. I have a simple problem, how to change the url for the displayed files(photos, videos) from wasabi to cdn?

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class WasabiServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Storage::extend('wasabi', function ($app, $config) {
            $conf = [
                'endpoint' => "https://" . $config['bucket'] . ".s3." . $config['region'] . ".wasabisys.com/",
                'bucket_endpoint' => true,
                'credentials' => [
                    'key' => $config['key'],
                    'secret' => $config['secret'],
                ],
                'region' => $config['region'],
                'version' => 'latest',
                'visibility' => $config['visibility'],
            ];
            $client = new S3Client($conf);
            $adapter = new AwsS3Adapter($client, $config['bucket'], $config['root'],['public'=>true]);
            $filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter,['visibility'=>$config['visibility']]);
            return $filesystem;
        });
    }
}
```

When I change the url for endpoint, uploading files to wasabi doesn't work.